# WSO2 SCIM 2 API to get all users by tenant not returning any user

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server, scim

I am using WSO2 identity server 5.7.0, i am calling the api https://[url]:[port]/t/tenantName/scim2/Users GET. The response received is the following with HTTP status 200:

```
 {"totalResults":0,"startIndex":1,"itemsPerPage":0,"schemas":["urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:ListResponse"]}
```

However, the user is not being returned, the tenant has its own admin user only. The expected response (working fine on another environment) is:

```
{
"totalResults": 1,
"startIndex": 1,
"itemsPerPage": 1,
"schemas": [
    "urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:ListResponse"
],
"Resources": [
    {
        "emails": [
            "user1@gmail.com"
        ],
        "meta": {
            "created": "2023-01-05T13:01:12Z",
            "lastModified": "2023-01-05T13:01:12Z"
        },
        "roles": [
            {
                "type": "default",
                "value": "Internal/subscriber,Internal/creator,Internal/publisher,Internal/everyone,admin"
            }
        ],
        "name": {
            "givenName": "user1",
            "familyName": "user1"
        },
        "id": "2e86d8e6-7db8-4600-a8bc-f3h1d54d8h6a",
        "userName": "user1"
    }
]
```

}

How to fix this? Are there any configuration that should be changed to return all users?

Note: SCIM is enabled in user-mgt.xml file

Comment: What did you mean by `working fine in another environment`? Was the same request succeeded with a different tenant / different IS server? The tried request is correct and there is nothing to configure special to get this worked

Comment: The same api call is returning the users correctly on a different identity server (same version) installed on a different server. Could it be a certain configuration that can enable/disable the return of users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recreating a new tenant after enabling the SCIM solved the issue, but the issue remains for the tenant that was created prior to enabling the SCIM.